# antlr4: token recognition error "." dot and other punctuation

Tags: parsing, antlr4

i have a parser rule defined as :

```
text: '"'.*?'"' ;
```

however this failes if the text contains punctuation '.'.

```
",;:!?./§/*-+)({}[]abc"   
line 1:1 token recognition error at: ','
line 1:2 token recognition error at: ';'
line 1:4 token recognition error at: '!'
line 1:5 token recognition error at: '?'
line 1:6 token recognition error at: '.'
line 1:7 token recognition error at: '/'
line 1:8 token recognition error at: '§'
line 1:9 token recognition error at: '/'
line 1:10 token recognition error at: '*'
line 1:11 token recognition error at: '-'
line 1:12 token recognition error at: '+'
line 1:13 token recognition error at: ')'
line 1:14 token recognition error at: '('
```

Oddly, curlies are recognized.
Any help to accept **anything** as part of a string?

Comment: Likely a problem involving a different rule in the grammar unintentionally attempting to consume the string. The 'curlies' are a hint. Try dumping the token stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `text` to be defined as a lexer rule like this:

```
TEXT: '"'.*?'"' ;
```

If using the wildcard operator in a parser rule ANTLR will match any rule instead of any character.

Comment: Should I always define a lexer rule for each parser rule?

Comment: Nope... Lexer rules are there in order to tokenize the input characters and parser rules are there to group these tokens in a certain way